# How to change label and radio button index

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
{
    Label1.Text = row["ques"].ToString();
    RadioButton1.Text = row["op1"].ToString();
    RadioButton2.Text = row["op2"].ToString();
    RadioButton3.Text = row["op3"].ToString();
    RadioButton4.Text = row["op4"].ToString();
}
```

In this code, for each time the loop runs, i want the value of `label1.text` gets changes to `label2.text`, then `label3.text` and soo on.

similarly with radiobutton.

Is this possible and how.

Comment: it's such a lovely task to use `yield`..

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't assembled your controls in array or list previously, the best you can do is with `FindControl`:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
{
    Label label = (Label)ParentControlId.FindControl(string.Format("Label{0}", i));
    label.Text = row["ques"].ToString();
    // same for radio buttons
    i++;
}
```

Note that `FindControl` should be called on the direct parent of the label or radio button.

Comment: The name 'ParentControlId' does not exist in the current context....

what to do for it???

Comment: @user3166111, of course it does not - this is just an example. We do not know your markup. You should find ouy direct parent control of your label/radiobutton, and substitute thid ID with yours. Example: if you have all your labels within panel with id Panel1, correct code would be `Panel1.FindControl`

Comment: now i am getting this error 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on "label.Text = row["ques"].ToString();"

Comment: @user3166111, either the label was not found or row["ques"] returns null. No way to tell which without details

Comment: one more thing i would like to ask you...

in database i have column having follwoing value...

"Specify <TABLE> tag alone displays ____________"

this is coming output as 

"Specify tag alone displays ____________"

how to display the thing correctly... means html tags too!!!

Comment: @user3166111, this is something completely different and should be asked in a separate question

Comment: I asked this to you, beacuse you know, how i am fetching the data... so, i need not to elobaote other, how i am fetching.. so if you can please help me out....

Comment: @user3166111, if you will create a new question, and explain what is your problem and what you have done so far - you will surely get help. It is not good to discuss this in comments